# Database synchronisation on the same sever for mysql

Tags: mysql, replication

I need to have two databases placed on the same mysql server synchronised.
This synchronisation is not used for replication, but for statistics, and the information on the second base do not have to be necessarily "fresh".

Currently, I'm doing a simple mysqldump every nigth, which could be a solution, but well, it's dirty.

So I thought about using mysql replication, and encountered 2 major problems :
- I can't figure how to make it work if the two databases are on the same server.
- I don't know how to perform the replication only once a day, at a precise time.

I'm using mysql 5.1.49 on windows (well, only for my tests, the production server is on linux), here is what I tried in my my.ini file

```
# Replication
server-id = 1

report-host = master-is-slave-host
log-bin = "d:/localhost-binlog"
log-error = "d:/localhost-errorlog"
relay-log = "d:/localhost-relaylog"

binlog-do-db = dev_nbe_msg_metier
replicate-rewrite-db = base1->base2

replicate-same-server-id = 1
```

The logs work fine, unfortunately that's all I can get, I tried several options, but could not make it work.

If anyone has a solution, or a better way to do this synchronisation, I'd be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out-of-the-box replication in MySQL assumes each server involved is, well, a server ;)

This means you can replicate between databases on the same physical machine only using two MySQL instances, each with its own server-id.

Happily, you can pause/restart replication almost at will, so on the slave machine each night you'd run:

```
start slave;
```

...leave it run for a while, and then when it's time to start production work again, run:

```
stop slave;
```

If you're feeling clever, you can use the `UNTIL` clause of `start slave` (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/start-slave.html)) to avoid having to stop the slave, and have it happen automatically once you've caught up.

There are other solutions, but with OOTB features, this might be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the start and stop think, I hadn't thought of that. Considering the other problem, do you think it's possible to run replication on a single mysql instance, limiting the replication to one database?

Comment: Not with MySQL replication - "each ID must be different from every other ID in use by any other replication master or slave", http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options.html#option_mysqld_server-id

Answer (score 0):

You can synchronize two databases with [Schema and Data Comparison tools](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-synchronization.html) in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).

There are also stand-alone tools:

- [dbForge Data Compare](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/datacompare/)
- [dbForge Schema Compare](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/schemacompare/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have to use native mysql stuff.

Comment: I don't like answer which simply link to _non-free_ software, especially when these answers come from the company providing the _non-free_ software. Feels a bit like *spam* ?